# sudo: ./TCP_Proxy.py: command not found

Tags: python, command, sudo

Heylo,

So I've been searching on why this is happening for two days now... I've read many threads on this site and tried all of the relevant advice given but to no avail.

When trying to run a TCP Proxy on a test ftp client I get the following error:

```
sudo: ./TCP_Proxy.py: command not found
```

The full command is:

```
sudo ./TCP_Proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.target.ca 21 True
```

I've tried

```
brew install sudo
```

to make sure that sudo is installed and it is.
I've also done the ls command and the file in question is indeed listed.
I'm kind of at a loss and would appreciate any help you may offer. Thank you.

CK

Comment: I've also tried specifying the whole path but that doesn't help either. :/

Comment: `TCP_Proxy.py` is executable?

Comment: Hi Gennady. When I type:

    python TCP_Proxy.py

I get the following response:

    Usage: ./TCP_Proxy.py [localhost] [localport] [remotehost] [remoteport]    [receive_first]
    Example: ./TCP_Proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 10.12.132.1 9000 True

So I believe it is executable. Using sudo because 21 is privileged port.

Comment: you should give permission the python file to excuse  first,either by `os.stat` and `os.chmod()`  from the inside or by just doing `sudo chmod +x TCP_Proxy.py`

Comment: Ahh! `sudo chmod +x TCP_Proxy.py` worked perfectly. THANK YOU! Doing this internally, should I add `os.stat` and `os.chmod()` before any of the code in 'TCP_Proxy.py'?

Comment: Trying to upvote y'all but cannot figure out how... Maybe because it's just a comment?

Comment: I just posted a full answer then :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo chmod +x TCP_Proxy.py` Will do the job,

Using Python,you could create a simple script that could be run first to give the intend file permission like:

```
import os
import stat

st = os.stat('TCP_Proxy.py')
os.chmod('TCP_Proxy.py', stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH)
```

The following are the full flags

> stat.S_IRWXU Mask for file owner permissions.
>
> stat.S_IRUSR Owner has read permission.
>
> stat.S_IWUSR Owner has write permission.
>
> stat.S_IXUSR Owner has execute permission.
>
> stat.S_IRWXG Mask for group permissions.
>
> stat.S_IRGRP Group has read permission.
>
> stat.S_IWGRP Group has write permission.
>
> stat.S_IXGRP Group has execute permission.
>
> stat.S_IRWXO Mask for permissions for others (not in group).
>
> stat.S_IROTH Others have read permission.
>
> stat.S_IWOTH Others have write permission.
>
> stat.S_IXOTH Others have execute permission.
>
> stat.S_ENFMT System V file locking enforcement. This flag is shared
>   with S_ISGID: file/record locking is enforced on files that do not
>   have the group execution bit (S_IXGRP) set.
>
> stat.S_IREAD Unix V7 synonym for S_IRUSR.
>
> stat.S_IWRITE Unix V7 synonym for S_IWUSR.
>
> stat.S_IEXEC Unix V7 synonym for S_IXUSR.

Comment: can you explain the "from the inside" point? and the `st = os.stat('somefile')` is useless.

Comment: `st = os.stat('some file')` gets the current permissions,,and meant giving the file permission by its self when it starts to run,not proper english anyway

Comment: I know that, but what's th e point of this python script? The chmod must be done from the shell right?

Comment: oh!my bad!now i get your point,if the `.py` file wasn't excutable the script won't run anyway,,the file should have permissions first right?meaning the script will only work if its external that it should be run first to give the intended file permissions first.

Comment: exactly my point.The python code is irrelevant (but you solved the OP issue)

Comment: i should remove the script part then :) ,or maybe i should just modify it so as maybe it could be used as a pythonic way to give file permissions!

Comment: yes, you could remove it. And the other part is off-topic here. Unless OP generates his python script using python :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't quite understand the 'some file' piece either, but that's ok. The original issue is now solved. Now it just listens forever. I generate my scripts using WingIDE for python.

@Arduino Sentinel I tried to upvote you but I apparently don't have enough street cred yet... 'People with a reputation under 15 votes are recorded but don't actually contribute to reputation.' I tried. I'm sorry.